# How do I get special cars?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just got GTA 5 for Xbox 360, and I heard of special cars, such as the Pegassi Zentorno. I asked a friend, and he told me just to walk in my garage, and so I did, and I clicked right on the d-pad and nothing happened.

How do I get special cars?

Comment: Are you trying to do this online or off? I added both tags for now. Also, can you be more specific about the cars you're trying to get?

Comment: Offline, well one of the cars that caught my eye was the pessagasi zentorno.

Comment: I haven't played this game in forever, so I'm not going to write an answer, but you can probably figure one out from this wiki page: http://gta.wikia.com/wiki/Zentorno

Comment: +1 for being a reasonable human being and providing more information. Welcome to Arqade! In the future, you should edit additional information into the question yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Head to the Xbox store and download all of the free GTA 5 DLC. Then once your in-game, drive to your nearest garage and you will have a whole bunch of special cars.

Comment: Do I have to sign in to x box live to do that?

Comment: Yes, you must have a gold Xbox live membership. If you aren't a gold member, most games have a 3 day gold trial in its case.

Comment: @Doc306 You need a gold account to play multiplayer games, but you can download DLC with a silver account. Do you actually need gold to get these DLC?

Comment: @DCShannon I stand corrected. I checked it out and it seems that silver does allow marketplace purchases.

Comment: @Jayston I have to apologize, I was certain it was gold. You are able to purchase with a Silver membership.

Answer (score 2):

I also have another way, of you complete a mission that gives you a car (like the space docker mission) when you get that car put it in a characters garage then (this worked for me) as another character go to the back of that characters garage and hit the right button on the d-pad and you will see a list that says special vehicles and you should see that cars name.